# Ajax POST from node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have Node.js server with Socket.IO, which communicate with Python server (Django).
I need to perform POST from the node.js server (on specific method) to the Django server.
I cannot use any jquery function because it require window document.

Any other idea how can i send data to the Django from Node.js with POST method and check if it success?

Thanks.

Comment: i am checking it right now, i will update here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [HTTP package](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Specifically use the [ClientRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) class to issue the POST request

Comment: not me.. i am reading about the packages you told me right now..

Answer (score 1):

https://npmjs.org/package/request

```
request.post('http://service.com/script', {form:{key:'value'}}, function(err,response,body){...});
```